# Drop Port Number on Apache Redirect Rule

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am trying to figure out a rewrite rule to drop port 81. I am using no-ip and so the request hits port 81 and then i have a rewrite rule to redirect to SSL. Now it looks like https://example.com:81 and I get a ssl error from it. Is there a way to drop the :81 after the ssl redirect?

Comment: What does the RewriteRule look like?

Answer (score 1):

The only fix for that would be to have your SSL listener running on port 443, not port 81.

HTTPS running on any port other than 443 will always, always have the port number in the URL.

Note that this is unlikely to fix your SSL validation error - there's likely a different reason for that.